# Program should produce one output value

Tags: python, math

This program still seems to print several outputs for a single
integration. The program should produce one output value (i.e., the
integral) for a single integration.

The inputs for a single integral are:

1. The function `f`
2. `a` = left endpoint
3. `b` = right endpoint
4. Numerical method (left, right, middle, trapezoid)
5. `n` = number of subdivisions
   The output is a single number, the integral.

```py
    from math import sin, pi
    f = lambda x: x*sin(x)
    a = 0
    b = pi/2
    n= 5
    h = (b-a) / n
    s = 0.5 * (f(a) + f(b))
    for i in range(1,n):
        s+= f(a + i*h)
        Integral = h * s
        print ('Integral  %f' % Integral)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Your print is inside a loop. Why are you surprised that it prints multiple times?

Comment: Move the lines `Integral = h * s` and `print(...)` outside the loop.

Comment: if you want to bind a function to a name, define a function, don't use a lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put the `print(...)` statement inside a `for` loop. Place it outside of the block of `for` loop.

```
from math import sin, pi
f = lambda x: x*sin(x)
a = 0
b = pi/2
n= 5
h = (b-a) / n
s = 0.5 * (f(a) + f(b))
for i in range(1,n):
    s+= f(a + i*h)
Integral = h * s
print ('Integral  %f' % Integral)
```